# MSChart Secondary AxisX2 AxisY2 Line Painting Location To Right and Upper Corner HowTo

Tags: mschart

Hello i am new to world of MSChart and was wondering why

LineColor, LineDashStyle, LineWidth of Secondary AxisX2 and AxisY2 keeps overlay on top at Primary AxisX and AxisY ?

MajorTickMark and MinorTickMark are shown as expected at top and right side of ChartArea,

Is it possible to Locate Line Style of Secondary Axes X2 Y2 to align at top and right side of ChartArea aswell some how ?

I was think of to use the chart1_PostPaint event to get this Line rectangle of X2 and Y2 being painted at top and right side location i looked at this event but even i don't have a clue if this is possible and right way to re locate the line painting of Secondary set of axes

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah set crossing of AxisX2 to appear AxisY2 at right side or move it anywhere,
solved it, what i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

At APP:  Over 200 Interactive Samples Of MSChart

At Sample:  Contents|Appearance: Axis Line Appearance

Located At:  \ChartFeatures\Axis\Appearance\cscode.txt

Is actually doing what i am looking for, the AxisY2 LineColor is painted at right side of chartarea
I looked at it's code but still find no clue how to align this AxisY2 Line to right side ??

hmmm i did set AxisX2 Crossing to zero maybe i should set this one to a higher max value
Now AxisY2 Line Color is located at zero instead of showing at right side aswell as its labels already do

Sorry to abuse this answer but i did try comments first
but comments function at this message board is stripping new lines and answer function is stripping new lines aswell some how